# How to get dictionary values in shape of lists with random.shuffle

Tags: python, dictionary

I seemed to have hit a small snag. I have a program that gets a dictionary with couple of keys and values:

```
dict = {"M" : ["L", "V", "A"], "C": ["N", "K", "W"]}
```

Now, I am trying to make a function that will, being provided a dictionary and a key from it, return that particular key's value, so:

```
def value(dictionary, key)
   return dictionary[key]
```

that I managed to succeed, but the problem arises when I try to return that particular list in a random order, working with `random.shuffle()`. It however keeps returning `None`. Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: Given that you don't bother showing the code (a [mcve] would be helpful), I can only guess that you haven't figured out that `shuffle` operates **in-place**, it doesn't return the shuffled list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as shuffle operates in-place, return the list after shuffle as follows:

```
from random import shuffle
sample_dict = {"M": ["L", "V", "A"], "C": ["N", "K", "W"]}


def get_value(dictionary, key):
    a = dictionary[key]
    shuffle(a)
    return a

b = get_value(sample_dict, "M")
print b
```